# The difference between how arrays are populated in ios?

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, plist

Hello and Thanks to All,
   Here is the situation, When I use the following methode to populate my array it works when I use Methode 2 it does not work.  The objective is to change the color of text.  Both Methods have been NSLOGED and the data is identical.

First way..(working name gets grayed out)

```
-cellForRowAtIndexPath
....
       if ([self.secArray containsObject:indexPath]) {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    } .....

-didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
...
  [secArray addObject:indexPath];
```

Second Way (not working - populate the Array from my .plist )

```
-cellForRowAtIndexPath
....
       if ([self.secArray containsObject:indexPath]) {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    } .....


-viewWillAppear
 NSString *filePathOrdersIndex = [self dataFilePathOrders];

    NSMutableArray *chekDist;

    chekDist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePathOrdersIndex];
    NSLog( @"data checkDist........... %@", chekDist);
    if(!chekDist){
        chekDist = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }

    for(id dist_data in chekDist){

        secArray = [dist_data objectForKey:@"myIndexPath"];
        //[secArray addObject:[dist_data objectForKey:@"myIndexPath"]];

    }
```

both methods logged to console both arrays contain Identical array data....but second way is not working

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It might because plists are NSDictionary representations...

Comment: @CodaFi, can you elaborate on representations ????

Comment: @CodaFi Yeah, the NSLog messages may even appear the same if the implementation of `NSIndexPath`'s `description` method prints text similar to a dictionary. @AhabLives: What he means is in the second method, since you're loading from a plist, you're likely looking at an instance of `NSDictionary` stored in the `"myIndexPath"` key rather than an actual `NSIndexPath` instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second method, you are assigning an element of the `checkDist` array to the array itself, is each `dist_data` in `checkDist` a `secArray`?

From an outside perspective, these two methods are not functionally equivalent without knowing more information about what kinds of data these variables hold. Though since you are setting the `secArray` variable each time the `for` loop executes, I'm assuming this is incorrect and you need to use the line you had commented-out in your second method (`[secArray addObject:[dist_data objectForKey:@"myIndexPath"]];`).

If after using that line instead it is still not working, verify that `secArray` has been created (make sure it's not `nil`) when the second method executes.

Comment: I tried the commented out line of code and it did not give me the desired format which is ....secArray = ("indexPath1","indexPath2","indexPath3","indexPath4")....the line above the commented  does give the desired format.